# React Native - How to maintain image ratio with width = "100%"?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

**I have images uris in my database, and I am rendering them with** `width: "100%"`

As images can be **1080x1080, 750x1080 and 1920x1080**, I need to find a way to render them **preserving the aspect rati**o... I mean, if I have the device's width is 600px, the image's width has to be 600px ("100%"), and its height has to be auto adapted, in order to avoid losing its ratio.

I have tried this **CSS**:

```
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
```

but only works for squared images (1080x1080). **How can I do** a `height: "auto"` **in react native**, so that the other images are resized with their correct aspect?

Important: **I don't know the dimensions of the images**, I only know that the image's width has to be equals to the device width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few step you have to take.

First you need to know the exact size of the image and that you do with `Image.getSize` or `Image.getSizeWithHeaders`

let me give an example below how you could do it.

```js
export interface ImageDetli {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  url: string;
}

const ImageRenderer = ({
  url
}: {
  url: string
}) => {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get("window").width);
  const [windowHeight, setWindowHeight] = useState(Dimensions.get("window").height);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // untill we load the image fully
  const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined as ImageDetli | undefined)
  const getSize = async(url: string) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // this is very imported so you can keep an eye on the size of the image
      Image.getSize(url, (width, height) => {
        resolve({
          url: url,
          width: width > windowWidth ? windowWidth : width,
          height: height > windowHeight ? windowHeight : height
        });
      }, async(error) => {
        console.log("image not loaded: " + url);
        console.log(error)
        resolve(undefined);

      })
    }) as Promise <ImageDetli | undefined>
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      var imageDetali = await getSize(url);
      if (!imageDetali){
        // load an empty Image or somthing
      }else {
        setImage(imageDetali);
      }
      setLoading(false)
    })();
  }, [])


  return (
  <>
  {loading?(<ActivityIndicator size="large"color="#0000ff"/>)
  :
  (
  <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", alignItems: "center", 
  justifyContent: "center" }}>
  <Image source={{uri: image.url}}
  style={{ width:image.width, height image.height, resizeMode: "contain" }} />
 </View>
  )}
  </>
  )
}
```

I hop you understand this, you may ask if you need to know more.

Comment: I have tested this, and working fine, thx. Also, I implemented another way which is working using CSS directly {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    resizeMode: "contain",
  } as I don't need to know image's size

Comment: If you do it with css it wont really work good on the device. I have tested this :)

Comment: do you mean in production? Or that it will fail in some devices? Also, take a look to this snack https://snack.expo.io/@victoriomolina/b361af it seems to work in both platforms. But... I think that might not work in old devices or something like that

Comment: No, If you do it with css, then you could try an image that are much smaller then the window size and you will see that the image will not look ok. the image raito will not be correct anymore.